# Как исправить ошибку DllNotFoundException?

Tags: unity3d, ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

Пишу приложение под `Linux` на `Unity`. И после добавления подключения к `wifi` через приложение появилась проблема

```
DllNotFoundException: wlanapi.dll. 
DllNotFoundException: wininet.dll.
```

Как исправить?

Comment: `под Linux`... .`подключения к wifi через приложение`.. Хочется спросить... Unity3D тут ваще по назначению используется? Или как лопата для забивания гвоздей?

Comment: По назначению, просто задачи нетривиальные...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я полагаю вы хотите использовать(или плагин который у вас подключен использует) Win32 api метод которого просто не существует в Linux и не может там оказаться.
Вам нужно посмотреть в сторону D-Bus и его NetworkManager. Возможно этот ответ вам будет полезен https://stackoverflow.com/a/40721703/8421100